# Помогите решить задачу с массивом в JS

Tags: javascript

[image: Условие задачи]

Не могу понять что от меня требуется. Мой вариант кода:

```
function makeStickers(detailsCount, robotPart) {
  let robots = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= detailsCount; i++)
  
    robots.push (` ${robotPart}  ${i}`);  
  
  return robots;
}
```

Comment: Покажите полный текст задачи.

Comment: По-моему всё понятно, что требуется. Там же пример выходного результат даже представлен

Comment: У вас как минимум нет знака `#`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не видно, какой массив в итоге получается.

Comment: @OliverPatterson массив строк. пример  результирующей строки указан

Comment: и опять же. наверняка ожидают точность, а не небрежность.... вот `\` $`  что за пробел?

Comment: @Max Forte, уберите пробел после апострофа и после "${robotPart}" допишите "detail" (без кавычек).

Comment: Спасибо кто откликнулся! получилось)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function makeStickers(detailsCount, robotPart) {
  const result = [];
  if (detailsCount === 0) {
    return result;
  }
  for (let i = 1; i <= detailsCount; i++) {
    result.push(`${robotPart} detail #${i}`);

  }
  return result;
}

console.log(makeStickers(3, 'body'));
```